# Accessing environment variable in when expression in jenkins pipelin

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline

Having conditional check inside when clause on expression check, its skipping due to non-match check.

```
def os_type
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages{
        stage('stage 1') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                echo "ver=1.3.0" > ${WORKSPACE}/some_file
                echo "os_type=win" > ${WORKSPACE}/some_file
                '''
            }
        }
        stage('stage 2') {
                steps {
                    script{         
                        os_type = sh(
                            script: "grep \"os_type\" ${WORKSPACE}/some_file | awk -F \"=\" '{print \$2}'",
                            returnStdout: true,
                        ).trim()
                }
            }
        } 
        stage('stage 3') {
            environment {
                enOS = "${os_type}"
            }
            steps {
                echo "enOS : ${enOS}"
                echo "env.enOS : ${env.enOS}"
                echo "os_type : ${os_type}"
            }
        }
        stage('stage 4') {
            environment {
                enOS = "${os_type}"
            }
            when { expression { "${env.enOS}" == 'win' } }
            steps {
                echo "From stage 2 conditional check : ${os_type}"
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Skip message printed from Stage 4 is per below :

```
[Pipeline] { 
Stage "stage 4" skipped due to when conditional
[Pipeline] }
```

Printing values without when clause check is just working fine. Is there a way to use defined/assigned environment variable for when clause check?

```
[Pipeline] echo (hide)
enOS : win

[Pipeline] echo
env.enOS : win

[Pipeline] echo
os_type : win

[Pipeline] }
```

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) spell out the correct syntax for a `when { environment { ... } }` block, which is:

```
        stage('stage 4') {
            environment {
                enOS = "${os_type}"
            }
            when { 
                environment { name: 'enOS', value: 'win' }
            }
            steps {
                echo "From stage 2 conditional check : ${os_type}"
            }
        }
```

That said, perhaps you can do this more elegantly by using a [`matrix`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-matrix) block? Example 34, reproduced here for posterity, will selectively ignore a platform based on a parameter passed at build time. It should be trivial to move the "When" block into a stage to selectively ignore that *stage* if that platform is selected.

```
pipeline {
    parameters {
        choice(name: 'PLATFORM_FILTER', choices: ['all', 'linux', 'windows', 'mac'], description: 'Run on specific platform')
    }
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('BuildAndTest') {
            matrix {
                agent {
                    label "${PLATFORM}-agent"
                }
                when { anyOf {
                    expression { params.PLATFORM_FILTER == 'all' }
                    expression { params.PLATFORM_FILTER == env.PLATFORM }
                } }
                axes {
                    axis {
                        name 'PLATFORM'
                        values 'linux', 'windows', 'mac'
                    }
                    axis {
                        name 'BROWSER'
                        values 'firefox', 'chrome', 'safari', 'edge'
                    }
                }
                excludes {
                    exclude {
                        axis {
                            name 'PLATFORM'
                            values 'linux'
                        }
                        axis {
                            name 'BROWSER'
                            values 'safari'
                        }
                    }
                    exclude {
                        axis {
                            name 'PLATFORM'
                            notValues 'windows'
                        }
                        axis {
                            name 'BROWSER'
                            values 'edge'
                        }
                    }
                }
                stages {
                    stage('Build') {
                        steps {
                            echo "Do Build for ${PLATFORM} - ${BROWSER}"
                        }
                    }
                    stage('Test') {
                        steps {
                            echo "Do Test for ${PLATFORM} - ${BROWSER}"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I liked `when { environment name: 'DEPLOY_TO', value: 'production' }` approach. Have added `trim()` to `sh` run on `stage 1` on OP, but somehow still comparison is not getting evaluated to `true` and `stage 4` is not getting executed. On `matrix` option, I need to opt in `expression` based since my pipeline uses dynamic data from generated file & not `param` based

Comment: And as per Jenkins doc, have added this condition `when { environment name: 'enOS', value: 'win' }` but somehow it is not getting evaluated to `true` even after adding `trim()` to OP

Comment: @vinWin hmm that's odd. I don't have access to a Jenkins instance to test this on, but per my understanding of what you're doing that _should_ work. I guess it's possible that the `when` block executes before the `environment` block, which would cause issues here for obvious reasons :)

Comment: Ah yes, the docs do imply that might be the case. "An environment directive defined within a stage will only apply the given environment variables to steps within the stage."

Comment: in that case, use `when { expression { os_type == 'win' } }`, referencing your global variable.